# Is NFS obsolete?

Tags: nfs

I'm trying to share files between several Linux machines. In 2023, is NFS a good way to do that?

I don't know much about NFS. I got the impression that NFS is old, buggy, unreliable, badly designed, and obsolete, and should only really be used for backwards compatibility with older systems. To what extent is that true? Is it sane to use NFS for new deployments? Is there something better I can use?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147461/discussion-on-question-by-mathematicalorchid-is-nfs-obsolete); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL;DR: No, NFS is still relevant, active, and a good choice in many situations.

---

## What Makes NFS (In)Appropriate for Your Use Case?

This really depends on your use case. I don't concur that NFS is generally obsolete or generally badly designed. It's definitely not "old" in the sense it hasn't been updated to match modern requirements: NFS 4.2 is from 2016, SMB 3.1.1 is from 2016, as well, and I don't know how many of each protocol revision's features are already implemented in the Linux kernel server and clients and Samba, respectively.

## State of NFS

It *is* an *Remote Procedure Call* (RPC) protocol: the things your client does over it is call *functions* on the server, and the server sends you the results. Your client then uses this mechanism to locally give you a file system.

This is pretty a pretty clean design – it's clear who's "owner" of the state, and that is something that usually makes distributed systems hard. However, that means that the whole system needs to be a little smart around things like varying network latencies. Something that you really want the newer versions of NFS for. Then, this functional approach is great: copying a file on the server is just a function call to the server; requesting some file contents from the middle of a large file is, and things like telling the server your software might need some parts of a file soon, will work very nicely – and inherently fit how a UNIX file system works a bit better than CIFS.

Sadly, *a lot* of the web's material on how to set up NFS are from the era of NFSv3  – which should have ended 23 years ago. But optimizing network protocols is hard, and so people copied over their best practices: some do still apply, some are just obsolete. In all frankness, NFS foremost has a documentation problem, as in, no good general guide for typical modern hardware and different network sizes and speeds. And a lot of people that think it's OK that you need to read a book or two before you start setting things up.

But, honestly, a default config on a Fedora-oid operating system probably is fine (don't have experience with NFS on others). You do, however, definitely want to "squash root" on every export, if at all possible, and you want real Kerberos authentication. That's super secure, "enterprise grade", Microsoft also bases its Active Directory on it as well. But it *is* an entry hurdle, and without it, your server is trusting the clients that the user they claim is accessing a file is actually that user.

## Alternatives

There's a few alternatives; listing all alternatives here is not going to work out (I'm not from that space), but the main things a small-network admin would encounter:

- SMB/CIFS, using Samba: The "Windows world compatible" approach. If set up correctly, might roughly approach NFS speeds. Can have performance problems when encrypted, setup requires separate keeping of user database (typically) or the same enterprise-grade "Active Directory" (alike) underpinning for user management as NFS. *Typically* laxer than NFS, i.e., there's situations where two different machines access the same file, and then these are different.
- iSCSI: if you need to export a file system read-only (for example, a static boot image archive): something that you can even early-boot from, different operating systems. More a "share my disk device" than a "share my files".
- SSHFS: fits the use case where only one user accesses the same files; has, lately, gained significant performance and stability improvement. But is now (July 2023), unmaintained since May 2022. Don't know whether I would want to bet on it long-term, but also, definitely not what you want for multiple users accessing the same files, since there's no coherence protocols built in. Client A, which already opened file x, will not see what Client B does to file x if the relevant part has already been transmitted locally (which it usually has).
- Lustere, Ceph filesystem, …: Typically, if your computers don't fill their own room, you're too small to care for these :)

So, really, out of all these alternatives, a Samba server would seem the only viable choice. Samba is the right choice if you need to interoperate with Windows, and it's the wrong choice if you care about the last 30% of performance and are willing to invest time.